# The precise meaning of "less to ... than to ..."?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> Alan's purpose was less to X than to Y. (X and Y are two verbs)

Does the above structure mean that

> Alan's purpose was not to X but it was to Y.

or instead it means that

> Alan had two purposes, "to X" and "to Y", but the second was more
>   important for him than the first.

?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own understanding as a native speaker:

The first sentence means that Alan wanted to do both X and Y, but his main purpose was Y.

Example:

```
Alan wanted to go to the party less to drink, but more to meet people.
```

This means that Alan wanted both to drink and meet people, but he wanted to meet people more so than drink.

In contrast:

```
Alan wanted to go to the party not to drink, but to meet people.
```

This means that Alan really didn't want to drink, he just wanted to meet people.